# Merge temporary account with actual

Tags: support, status-completed

I have a registered Stack Exchange account (gamedev.stackexchange & meta.stackexchange) https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/1424/cobalthex

but I also have an unregistered  another gamedev.stackexchange account (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/13448/cobalthex) that I would like to merge. This account was originally created on my phone because I browse Stack Exchange on opera mini which screws with the login page (the openID panel). I was wondering if someone could merge the accounts (the email address & names are the same).

Answer (score 2):

I merged your accounts. In the future, feel free to just [flag one of your posts for moderator attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232). :)